# Trying to setup Bitbucket GIT repo inside of Codio

Tags: bitbucket, codio

I just signed up for the premium version of Codio and i'm trying to setup an existiing repo i have on BitBucket.org. When i try to connect to the repo it tells me i need to upload a public SSH key to my host. (see screenshot)

The problem is i'm not sure what information to fill in here, when i try host: bitbucket.org and my credentials it says it cannot connect

Has anyone else experienced this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doug

BitBucket don't allow SSH Shell access which is what Codio is using in the dialog. For now (as you've seen) copy the key out from your Codio account and add in manually to your BitBucket Account.

We'll get this looked into to improve